# Understand javascript objects in order to import them into mysql database

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a export.js file in the following format. A user is giving me data in this format, i need to add it to my database

```
   index = {
  "me" : {
    "id" : "524bd089-2a7b-4a71-ba23-16354d6351ae",
    "firstName" : "Arjun",
    "lastName" : "Tuli",
    "pictureName" : "66s2c.jpg",
    "username" : "arjun-tuli"
  },
  "spaces" : [ {
    "user" : {
      "id" : "524bd089-2a7b-4a71-ba23-16354d6351ae",
      "firstName" : "Arjun",
      "lastName" : "Tuli",
      "pictureName" : "66s2c.jpg",
      "username" : "arjun-tuli"
    }
  }, {
    "user" : {
      "id" : "60c4a171-172f-4f66-9014-8b4cf3e476e6",
      "firstName" : "Banun",
      "lastName" : "Idris",
      "pictureName" : "../../../../default-pic/butterfly_200.png",
      "username" : "banun-idris"
    }
  } ]
}

users["524bd089-2a7b-4a71-ba23-16354d6351ae"] = {
  "id" : "524bd089-2a7b-4a71-ba23-16354d6351ae",
  "firstName" : "Arjun",
  "lastName" : "Tuli",
  "pictureName" : "66s2c.jpg",
  "username" : "arjun-tuli",
  "libraries" : [ "lEy27AZavfSR", "l0yApAoo2l4b", "lJl22YOtacxY", "l0UhMCvrMmka", "lJMWpIoFnaK4", "lCZ9cYYjVJcv", "l8kynpyoaej7" ]
}

    libraries["lEy27AZavfSR"] = {
      "id" : "lEy27AZavfSR",
      "name" : "My Main Library",
      "description" : null,
      "numKeeps" : 0,
      "keeps" : [ ]
    }
libraries["l0yApAoo2l4b"] = {
  "id" : "l0yApAoo2l4b",
  "name" : "My Private Library",
  "description" : null,
  "numKeeps" : 0,
  "keeps" : [ ]
}
```

I not only need to get the data but also get the following value index->me->id.

And for that id, i need to get all the libraries.

I tried this code, including the file in my script and then using ajax to send the information to a php file.

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
// here i include the file with export data file 
    $.getScript('trial_data.js', function()
    {
    console.log(index["me"]["id"]);
        // script is now loaded and executed.
      });
    </script>
```

It just says that the index variable is undefined, what can i do to get the data from the export.js file into the database

Comment: If i console.log(libraries) it returns a result

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned exactly how the user **gives** you the data, so here are two scenarios:

1. if you get to run JavaScript on a page where you can load that script with jQuery, just make sure the path is correct (trial_data.js is in the same path as the page it's running on, or traverse accordingly).
2. if you can get that json literal on server side directly, you can just load it in PHP with `json.decode`

Comment: The user uploads, a file. Plus the path is correct, the other variables i can console. when i try to console index it says, it is not defined. I tried the PHP thing also but it doesn't work as the file is not in json format, also i can;t figure out the regex to get the following value in php index->me->id